# How can I make apply_filter only apply to a specific product in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I've written some filters to disable plugin functionality of Customer Specific Pricing by WisdmLabs. These are the filters I've wrote

```
add_filter ( 'wdm_csp_calc_simple_prod_price', '__return_false' );
add_filter ( 'wdm_csp_show_total_price', '__return_false' );
add_filter ( 'wdm_csp_show_quantity_based_price', '__return_false' );
add_filter ( 'wdm_csp_apply_quantity_price_in_cart', '__return_false' );
```

However this applies it to the entire store but I just need to apply it to a single product. Could anyone help with with the code to apply these filters just for one product?

Comment: You should need to provide the complete function arguments (variables) available for each of the four hooks. Without it nobody can help you.

Comment: This is just what the plugin developer sent me and it seems to work but for all products. They take about a week to reply to any support tickets so wondered if anyone here would be able to help. Where do I find the variables?

Comment: As we dont have your plugin, we can't guess where those filters are active (on archive pages, on single product pages, on cart items, on order items)… So you should better ask WisdmLabs developers or hire a developer than can look in the plugin sourde code and make that work. **Your question is just not answerable actually.**

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty new to delving into the code of WordPress. I've been tased to create a new website for work that has to go live tonight and there's been so much complexity involved with the way my boss wants to do everything.

Comment: Then your boss should hire a real developer that is used specifically to Woocommerce to finalize those little difficult remaining things.